# Ionic 2 : Set interval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I try to set an interval in a .ts file but I don't understand how to use a function in the same file in the interval.

To explain :

My interval setting :

```
this.task = setInterval(function () {
            this.refreshData();
        }, 300);
```

And my function in the same ts file :

```
refreshData() : void{
        console.log('update...');
    }
```

When I run on my device, I have this error :

```
04-19 10:38:57.535 21374-21374/com.ionicframework.app722890 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(79432)] "TypeError: this.refreshData is not a function
                                                                                      at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:10987:18
                                                                                      at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10284)
                                                                                      at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:39626:37)
                                                                                      at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:10220)
                                                                                      at e.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7637)
                                                                                      at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:11397)
                                                                                      at e.args.(anonymous function) (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:2:30193)", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (79432)
```

I try this way but I doesn't work :

```
this.task = setInterval(this.refreshData(), 300);
```

This call my function only one time.

Someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use arrow function

```
this.task = setInterval(() => {
  this.refreshData();
}, 300);
```

or store context like this

```
let self = this;
this.task = setInterval(function () {
  self.refreshData();
}, 300);
```

or using `bind`

```
this.task = setInterval((function () {
  this.refreshData();
}).bind(this), 300);
```

if only one function call:

```
this.task = setInterval(this.refreshData.bind(this), 300);
```

you could learn more about this with https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md

Comment: Arrow function is what was needed ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use setInterval() with => arrow, as I mentioned below

```
   setInterval(() => {      
          console.log('timer');
          //you can call function here
    },5000);
```

100% working.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: For future reference: The reason this works is because `() => {}` injects the current context or "this" into the callback context of whatever it's used in. If you do `(something) => {}` it will make "something" available in the same manner, this may be a variable, function, or whatever. Mind the wording, a good professional explanation is found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
setInterval(this.refreshData, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code in my app.

This worked:

```
this.task = setInterval( () => {
  this.refreshData();
}, 300);
```

Comment: sir in foreground its working but not working if app is background ?