# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined while pushing data in public array

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to push some values in array on function call. I got the vaues in function but when I am trying to push those values in array I am getting the error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. However I have initialize the array as public as per the typescript format. Yet, I am unable to find where I am doing mistake. I am new to angular so please pardon for silly errors.

```js
    export class AppHome
    {
      public pick_markers:Array<object> = [];
      public dest_markers:Array<object> = [];   

      constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.codeAddress('Av. da Liberdade, 1250-096 Lisboa, Portugal','pickup');
      }

      codeAddress(address: string,type) {
        console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        let latlng:any;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
          console.log(status);
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            let get_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            let get_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            if(type=='dest') {
              this.dest_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log(this.dest_markers);                       
            } else if(type='pickup') {
              this.pick_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log('pickuplatlng--lat::'+this.lat+',,,lng::'+this.lng);
            } else {
              console.log('no input');
            }
          } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are pointing wrong `this`, using arrow function or store context as following examples:

```
    export class AppHome
    {
      public pick_markers:Array<object> = [];
      public dest_markers:Array<object> = [];   

      constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.codeAddress('Av. da Liberdade, 1250-096 Lisboa, Portugal','pickup');
      }

      codeAddress(address: string,type) {
        console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        let latlng:any;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, (results, status) => {
          console.log(status);
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            let get_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            let get_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            if(type=='dest') {
              this.dest_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log(this.dest_markers);                       
            } else if(type='pickup') {
              this.pick_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log('pickuplatlng--lat::'+this.lat+',,,lng::'+this.lng);
            } else {
              console.log('no input');
            }
          } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

or:

```
    export class AppHome
    {
      public pick_markers:Array<object> = [];
      public dest_markers:Array<object> = [];   

      constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.codeAddress('Av. da Liberdade, 1250-096 Lisboa, Portugal','pickup');
      }

      codeAddress(address: string,type) {
        console.log(address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        let latlng:any;
        const self = this; // <= store context
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
          console.log(status);
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            let get_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            let get_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            if(type=='dest') {
              self.dest_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log(this.dest_markers);                       
            } else if(type='pickup') {
              self.pick_markers.push({lat:+get_lat,lng:+get_lng});
              console.log('pickuplatlng--lat::'+this.lat+',,,lng::'+this.lng);
            } else {
              console.log('no input');
            }
          } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

for better, you could define an interface to declare the shape of object like this:

```
interface Coords {
  lat: number;
  lng: number
}

public pick_markers:Array<Coords> = [];
public dest_markers:Array<Coords> = [];
```

for more solutions, please read this thread:
[Ionic 2 : Set interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490761/ionic-2-set-interval/43490813#43490813)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of wrong initialization of an array.

Initialize Array like this, it will work

```
 dest_markers :Array<any>=[];
 pick_markers :Array<any>=[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the array declaration.

try,

> ```
> pick_markers: any[];
> dest_markers: any[];
>
> this.pick_markers.push('data');
> this.dest_markers.push('data');
> ```