# core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am building and api to include linkedin login in Angular. I used the doc of Linkedin here to do it step by step :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

I console.log the url to send to have the token, everything is fine but i still have: "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined". All the informations are find in the url sent by post to fetch the result.

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import {  HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    //INTERFACE UTILISATEUR
    import { User } from './user.model';

    import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

    import { Observable, of, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

    export class AuthService {

    //PROPERTIES --------------
      user$: Observable<User>;
      state:string = '<hide>';
      clientID: String = '<hide>';
      keyID: String = '<hide>';
      urlLinkedin = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${this.clientID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/authentification/sign-in&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social&state=${this.state}`;
      windowAttributes:string = "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=520,height=700";
      windowTarget:string = "_blank";
      codeRecup:string;
      subscription$: Subscription;
      sendURL:string;

    //END PROPERTIES --------------

    //CONSTRUCTOR
      constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private afs: AngularFirestore,
        private router: Router,
        private http:HttpClient
      ) {}

    //Linkedin  ---------------------- 
    linkedinSignin(){
        window.open(this.urlLinkedin, this.windowTarget, this.windowAttributes);
        window.addEventListener('message', this.linkedinGetCode, false);
      }

    linkedinGetCode (event){
      this.clientID =  '<hide>';
      this.keyID = '<hide>';

      if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:4200")
      return;
      this.codeRecup = event.data;

      this.sendURL = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`+
      `&grant_type=authorization_code`+
      `&code=${this.codeRecup}`+
      `&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/authentification/sign-in`+
      `&client_id=${this.clientID}&client_secret=${this.keyID}`;

    //URL to get the token is perfect
      console.log(this.sendURL);

      this.http.post(this.sendURL,{headers: new HttpHeaders({'Host': 'www.linkedin.com', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})}
        ).subscribe(responseData =>
          {
            console.log(responseData), err => console.error(err)
          });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are losing context. try this

```
window.addEventListener('message', this.linkedinGetCode.bind(this), false);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks you very much for you're time and answer. It's working now i get back the answer from linkedin, with adding you´re solution. Can u explain where i loosed context? When i was console log the URL it was fine. Just before to send it to the http.post.

Comment: I found this informations about Binding, that you put in you re answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Comment: @Jeremie-Segu because you're assign the function to a callback, this can lead to losing `this` (pointing to another object). we can prevent by store the context or using bind. More solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490761/ionic-2-set-interval/43490813#43490813

Comment: Thanks you very much, ill study this solution and apply it to my code. Have a nice day and thanks you again for you re time.

Answer (score 0):

**The code working with Tiep Phan solution :**

```
linkedinSignin(){
    window.open(this.urlLinkedin, this.windowTarget, this.windowAttributes);
    window.addEventListener('message', this.linkedinGetCode.bind(this), false);
  }

linkedinGetCode (event){
  this.clientID =  'hide';
  this.keyID = 'hide';
  //Si le message en provenance du Child a une autre origine que la  Window parente alors on stop tout
  if (event.origin !== "http://localhost:4200")
  return;
  //On récupère le code pour générer un TOKEN
  this.codeRecup = event.data;
  //console.log(this.codeRecup);
  //On prépare l URL pour POSTER le code et recevoir le TOKEN
  this.sendURL = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`+
  `&grant_type=authorization_code`+
  `&code=${this.codeRecup}`+
  `&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/authentification/sign-in`+
  `&client_id=${this.clientID}&client_secret=${this.keyID}`;
  console.log(this.sendURL);
  this.http.post(this.sendURL,{headers: new HttpHeaders({'Host': 'www.linkedin.com', 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})}
    ).subscribe(responseData =>
      {
        console.log(responseData), err => console.error(err)
      });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```